# A property/result which does seem to be dependent on number system but is independent.

Tags: number-systems

Would you tell a property/result which does seem to be dependent on the number system(base) but is independent of the number base?

Comment: Here is one: $11^2=121$.

Comment: And for dissimilar digits with an operator between them. Ignore zero contained digits.

Comment: The base $b$ expansion of $x$ is (ultimately) periodic.